# I'm trying to make a CRUD and I'm not able to send the <Select> data with 'react-select' dependencie

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to make a CRUD and I'm not able to send the  data. All other data is being saved without problem, but the one related to 'Select' is not. How do I do? Thanks.

```
const initialValue = {
  tenants: '',
  options: '', 
  tenantOptions:''
}


const [tenantOptions, setTenantsOptions] = useState([]);


//.. rest of the code omitted

//.. rest of the code omitted

   <form method="post" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
     <div className="form-group row mt-3">
       <label className="col-md-3 label-control form- 
           label">Tenants</label>
           <div className="col-md-8">
           <Select
             options={tenantOptions}                      
             onChange={obj => dispatch(selectContract(obj && obj.value ? 
             obj.value : ''))}  
             name="tenants"
             id="tenants"
             className="select-group"
             isSearchable={true}                     
             isClearable={true}
             theme={headerSelectTheme}
             />
      </div>
```

All other data is being saved without problem, but the one related to 'Select' is not. How do I do? Thanks.

```
const saveCsv = (data, cb) => {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_MYAPP_URL}/api/orders/csv`, data, {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        cb(response);
        console.log('response: ')
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        cb({
          error: true,
          message: error.message,
          status: error.response && error.response.status ? error.response.status : ''
        });
      });
  };
  
  
  function onSubmit(evt) {
   
    saveCsv(values, res => {
      evt.preventDefault()
      if (res.error) {
        toast.error('Failed to generate CSV file!')
        setModalLoading(false)
        return
      }

      toast.success('Tenant CSV file created.')
    
      setModal(false)     
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The obj param in the onChange callback is an event object and not a DOM node. You can get the DOM node by access the `event.target` property.

So instead of `obj.value` you should be checking for `obj.target.value`

`onChange={obj => dispatch(selectContract(obj && obj.value ? obj.value : ''))}`

becomes

`onChange={obj => dispatch(selectContract(obj && obj.target && obj.target .value ? obj.target.value : ''))}`

Comment: I think that should fix it

Comment: It didn't work, there in the 'response' it didn't appear. Maybe is there another missing step to solve? thanks